# Laurent series expansion of $f(z)=\frac 1{z^2+z+1}$ for $|z| > 1$ centered at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Since $|z| > 1$, with finding a convergent series in mind I wanted to write an equivalent closed-form expression of $f$ in terms of $\frac 1z$ because $|\frac 1z| < 1$. So I tried to factor out $\frac 1{z^2}$ and writing $f$ as follows:
$$
f(z) = \frac 1{z^2}\frac 1{1 - (-\frac 1z - \frac 1{z^2})}.
$$
However, $|-\frac 1z - \frac 1{z^2}| \le \frac 1{|z|}+\frac 1{|z|^2} < 1+1=2$, so I was unable to bound $|-\frac 1z - \frac 1{z^2}|$ by $1$.

What is a suitable expression of $f$ that I would need so that I can finally rewrite it in terms of a convergent series?

Should I consider splitting into two cases: $1 < |z| \le 2$ and $|z| > 2$? It turns out that if $|z| > 2$, then $|-\frac 1z - \frac 1{z^2}| \le \frac 1{|z|}+\frac 1{|z|^2} < \frac 12 + \frac 12 = 1$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{z^2+z+1}=\frac{1/(w-w^2)}{z-w}+\frac{1/(w^2-w)}{z-w^2}=\frac{1}{z}\frac{1/(w-w^2)}{1-w/z}+\frac{1}{z}\frac{1/(w^2-w)}{1-w^2/z}$, where $w=e^{2\pi i/3}$. Now expand $\frac{1}{1-w/z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{w}{z}\right)^n$ and likewise the other term.

Comment: How did you get the first equality? Did you factor $z^2+z+1$ into imaginary factors and then used partial fractions?

Comment: Yes, that is how you do many computations with rational functions, in particular Laurent expansions.

Comment: I'm still not sure how you got the RHS of your first equality; doing the distinct factor case of the method of partial fractions, I got $$\frac 1{(z+w)(z-w)} = \frac{-\frac 1{2w}}{z+w} + \frac {\frac 1{2w}}{z-w}$$ where $w=e^{\frac{2\pi i}3}$.

Comment: The roots of $z^2+z+1$ are not $w$ and $-w$, are $w$ and $\overline{w}=w^2=1/w$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $|z|>1$ we can consider $|w|=\left|\dfrac{1}{z}\right|<1$, then
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{z^2+z+1}
&= \dfrac{w^2}{1+w+w^2} \\
&= \dfrac{w^2(1-w)}{1-w^3} \\
&= (w^2-w^3)(1+w^3+w^6+\cdots) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{z^2}-\dfrac{1}{z^3}+\dfrac{1}{z^5}-\dfrac{1}{z^6}+\dfrac{1}{z^8}-\dfrac{1}{z^9}+\cdots
\end{align}